# Safely changing UserID's, re-using deleted UserID's and automatically using deleted userID's instead of an increment

Tags: users, user-meta, sql, user-registration, id

I'm looking for 3 different solutions all relating to user ids, I'm needing a solution to safely make changes without destroying the site.

## Issue 1:

- I am wanting to change the userID of a user from UserID 507 to userID 10.

## Issue 2:

- I am wanting to manually user a deleted UserID, basically the user 5 was deleted by accident and was only noticed two months later and we want to register a user to this userID.

## Issue 3:

- We have a plugin that generates a "temporary account" if someone registers through certain channels and then when they finalize their registration it merges this into a new account so all of our user ID's are separated by 1 user.
- User 2 = temp/deleted, user 3 = real user, user 4 = temp/deleted, user 5 = real user... etc
- We want all these blank/non existent user ids to be filled with actual users.

---

The solution for 1 or 3 could be a solution for 2, either will work. For 1 and 2 I am perfectly fine having as a SQL query.

Any pointers or suggestions on ways to achieve these?

Comment: This really isn't how user IDs are supposed to be used. If you need sequential user numbers for business reasons then you should use a separate custom field, and not rely on a database ID.

Comment: Of course it's not how they're supposed to be used, I know that. That doesn't help me in do what I am wanting though.